# Short and Sweet Entry into topical challenge #41

Tags: word-property

> Al Diner is from ________
>
> Don Shura is from ________
>
> Meg Ryan is from _______

Please do not use computer or the net. Becomes too  easy.

Comment: You should [edit the challenge post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/6503/edit) and add this as an entry if you want a chance to receive the cash and prizes associated with the FTC. :)

Comment: Without using the net, I wouldn't even be able the read this puzzle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think these are

> Country anagrams

So

Al Diner is from ________

> Ireland

Don Shura is from ________

> Honduras

Meg Ryan is from _______

> Germany.